# Ultra-high temperature heat pump possibilities

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger

How can I best transfer heat from space A [200ºC, 200 bar] to space B [1060ºC, 200 bar] using a heat pump style method? Both spaces are air filled.

Keeping in mind typical material limitations, a typical heat pump might be impossible.

Initial concept is to expand the 1060ºC air to ambient pressure, pass through a heat exchanger with the 100ºC air, and then recompress.

Any more elegant solutions?

Comment: Heat pumps are classically based on the energy used for latent changes gas to liquid & liquid to gas to get the efficiency in "normal" units. What fluids have you considered that are liquid at 200 deg C and gas at 1060 deg C?

Comment: You need to look at the decomposition reactions. About 5% of the atoms may undergo changes if you turboexpand the high temp air. Since you are going from about 575 K to 1435 K, what coefficient of performance would you expect from a heat pump?

Comment: @PhilSweet Performance isn't a limiting factor, but I'd hope for higher than 100%. Decomposition reactions sound interesting, do you have a resource available that might be specifically relevent to my challenge?

Comment: @SolarMike I believe there will be many fluids that fit that requirement. At the elevented pressure (preferably) there are likely many more.

My guess is that for a heat pump concept to opperate efficiently here, the ΔT would need to be smaller. So perhaps a multi-stage heat pump that gradually increases temperature up to above 1060ºC in order to allow for heat exchange.

Thoughts?

Comment: Will multi-stages increase the losses?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I would expect so. But efficiency isn't vital in this situaltion.